# Get amount of shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a little bit confused with the Facebook Graph API.

As i have found out it is possible to get the amount of shares of a specific link.

I have tried it and it works pretty well, but the problem is, that it does not count when one specific user (when I) share the link directly on my wall.

Does anyone know any possible solution to get all the shares?

All the best

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear as to which API are you using but you can get the number of shares for a link using this Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/?id=<your_link>&access_token=<your_access_token>
```

The response object contains the share count for your link:

```
"share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 1234
   },
```